# Calculate with quaternions in matrix form

Tags: matrices, vectors, quaternions

I am working on a software implementation of Matrices, Quaternions and Vectors ($\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$), but I want all of them to use matrices as underlying form.

I already found out that a vector dot product equals  $\vec{a}^T \ \vec{b}$, but what about:

- **cross products**
- **hamilton products**
- **quaternion multiplication**?

Can they, too, be represented as matrix operations?

Comment: Isn’t one of the motivating reasons for using quaternions in software that they’re more computationally efficient than the equivalent matrix operations?

Answer (score 0):

See [cross product matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Conversion_to_matrix_multiplication) and the [matrix representations of quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Matrix_representations) on Wikipedia.